# How do I parse this JSON structure?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

How do I parse this JSON? I dont know how to define this structure:

```
[
    [{
        "timestamp": 1324374926
    }],
    [{
        "id": "9",
        "neme": "qqq"
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "neme": "qqq"

    }, {
        "id": "29",
        "neme": "qqq"
    }]
]
```

JSON parsing code:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Categor[]));
 Categor[] result = (Categor[])serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

by defining data contracts...

Compiler is returning:

> System.InvalidCastException: InvalidCastException    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToDataContract(DataContract
>   contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson
>   context)    at
>     System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.ObjectToDataContractConverter.ConvertICollectionToCollectionDataContract(DataContractJsonSerializer
>   serializer, CollectionDataContract contract, Object deserializedValue,
>   XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ConvertObjectToDataContract(DataContract
>   contract, Object value, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson
>   context)    at System.Runtime.Serializati

How do I parse this JSON?

Matter is that for normal JSON I am creating fe:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Categor[]));
 Categor[] result = (Categor[])serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
[

{
    "category": "A",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "id": "QW",
            "name": "A",
            "ranking": 100,
            "isVisible": true
        },
        {
            "id": "QWN0d",
            "name": "Pol",
            "ranking": 101,
            "isVisible": false
        },
```

...

The data model is:

```
   [DataContract]
    public class Articlesubcat
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "ranking")]
        public string ranking { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "isVisible")]
        public string isVisible { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Categor
    {
           [DataMember(Name = "category")]
        public string category { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "subcategories")]
        public List<Articlesubcat> subcat { get; set; }
    }
```

But in this JSON aparently I have:

```
[
[
 {
    "timestamp": 1324374926
 }
],
[
  {
    "id": "9",
    "neme": "qqq"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "19",
    "neme": "qqq"

   },
   {
    "id": "29",
    "neme": "qqq"
   }
 ]
]
```

and as i see i don't know how to prepair model for this 2 object (array objects) or i don't even know what is name of this structure.

Comment: What is a `Categor`? Please show the code.

Comment: You'll need to show your data model as well.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't show us the declaration of `Categor`, `Categor[]` cannot be the correct root type of your JSON data.

The JSON data is an *array* of *array* of something. So your root data type needs to be something like `Categor[][]`.

**Update:**

Thanks for posting the declaration of `Categor`. It's now clear that your JSON sample is not an array of `Categor` instances. Instead, it's an array of two elements. The first one is an array of some unknow object types. It contains a property called `timestamp`. So it cannot be a `Categor` instance. The second element is an array of `Categor` instances (and probably the part you are expecting).

With some luck, you can parse the JSON with the root type `Categor[][]` and then just use the second element of the outmost array. If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to switch to an alternative JSON library since `DataContractJsonSerializer` has some limitations with arrays of mixed types.